# String.startwith Vs regex

Tags: javascript, regex

There is a dynamic string and I want to validate whether it starts with 'image'. For that I'm using below code snippet.

```
var isValidImage = inputType.startsWith('image');
```

Is this the recommended way or should I use regX here? What is the best option?

Comment: You're asking if the `string.startsWith` method is recommended to check if a *string starts with* a value? What's the catch? Why do you think a method that does exactly what you want may not be recommended? Is there something in particular on your mind?

Comment: Use regex when you know the *pattern* that can be described with regular expressions. If you have a literal value, you can use `startswith`/`indexOf`/`includes`/etc.

Comment: Do you care about case sensitivity?

Comment: @squint: `startsWith()` is ECMA 6 and doesn't work in *any* IE version at the moment.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ: Yes, I know. I also know that it's easily patched if that was the actual concern.

Comment: If it doesn't work with IE, is it really a problem? *(<-- troll inside)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you care about case sensitivity then you could use a regex

```
var isValidImage = /^image/i.test(inputType);
```

If not then you can just use `startsWith`, but keep in mind browser compatibility. You might need a [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Polyfill).

It is simpler to just use the regex which is compatible everywhere.

Comment: Good call on the polyfill and the case-insensitive

Answer (score 0):

I know this is years later but just wanted to comment that using a regex has, surprisingly noticeable better performance (~+50%) compared to `startsWith` or `indexOf`. I'm guessing the regex engine is highly optimized and probably just passes pointers to c code to actually execute.  In most cases it probably doesnt matter but if you're iterating over large data sets checking for matches then use `//.test`. Also I didnt test in node so the performance may be different but I did test many different browsers.

Here is a very simple jsbench comparison that you can run in your browser: https://jsbench.me/09lqlgolrr/1

Comment: I doubt that this benchmark (on constant literal expressions) is representative

Comment: @Bergi agree. This is a super simple case just for illustration purposes. I should have also included [this](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/4797/1/js-regex-vs-startswith-vs-indexof) which is probably more realistic.

Answer (score -2):

Many of the String object's pattern-matching methods do, in fact, use implicit RegEx objects behind the scenes. I'm not sure if .startsWith() does, but when you can go either way, you can just pass a string (if it is a static value you are working against, rather than a pattern). This is all optimized away and is perfectly fine to use, rather than explicit RegEx instances.

Comment: Any source about that?

Comment: They do? Hard to believe that they'd construct a RegExp object to do a simple search. I'd be curious to see evidence of this.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Here's how String.match() works. Others do the same: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: `.match()` is specifically meant to receive a regex. That doesn't have anything to do with any other method.

Comment: Most of the pattern-matching methods work like this. Here's .split()  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search

Comment: And String.search() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search

Comment: Again, those are methods specifically designed to (perhaps optionally) receive a regex. It has no impact on `startsWith` or any method that is not designed that way.

Comment: @squint You are making my point. The question asked whether a string literal should be used or RegEx. My response was that in many pattern-matching methods you can do either because (as you confirm my point) they are designed to take RegEx objects but create new ones implicitly when one isn't provided.

Comment: *"Many...use implicit RegEx objects behind the scenes... This is all optimized away and is perfectly fine to use..."* Two that are documented to create a regex for you are not many. The `.split()` method doesn't do that... your link is to the `.search()` method. The MDN wording is poor on the other two, since by documenting it, it is in fact explicit.

Comment: @squint I have provided 3 links (match, split & search) and don't see what is poor wording about "A regular expression object. If a non-RegExp object obj is passed, it is implicitly converted to a RegExp by using `new RegExp(obj)`."  I don't see what your issue is here?!

Comment: @squint You can add .replace() to the list as well. I said that "many of the pattern matching methods..."  I didn't say all or even most. What's the problem here?

Comment: Your link to `.split()` is actually pointing to `.search()`. Both `.replace()` and `.split()` can receive a regex, but neither do any sort of conversion. Your answer says many take the string you provide and implicitly convert it to a regex to perform their task. That's not the case, unless you can show an implementation that actually does that in practice. Only `.match` and `.search` are explicitly spec'd do that. *(BTW, I didn't downvote you.)*

Comment: @squint Yes, my mistake on the incorrect link. `.search()` and `match()` do exactly what I said. The documentation is quite clear: *If a non-RegExp object obj is passed, **it is implicitly converted to a RegExp by using new RegExp(obj)**. Again, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Yes, `.match()` and `.search()` are explicitly documented to do that conversion. The other ones don't convert your string to a regex. The problem is that your answer *(especially its original wording)* makes it sound as though implementations take your string and implement the method behavior by first converting your string to a regex. That's only the case in those two methods, and only because that's what the spec requires explicitly. If you can show me code for an implementation that actually makes a practice of using regex in place of your string argument beyond that, I'll stand corrected.

Comment: @squint I don't know what you are looking for here. I am saying that implementations convert strings to new RexEx instances and that is backed up by the documentation that I've shown.  What exactly is your point here?

Comment: I already told you my point. There are two methods with that specific behavior. Your answer sounds much more generalized, which again, there's no reason to believe. Question is *"we have `startsWith`, should I use regex instead"* your answer is *"Many of the String object's pattern-matching methods do, in fact, use implicit RegEx objects behind the scenes... all this is optimized away"*. This is very misleading. The text you added is a tiny bit better, but then *"...all this is optimized away"* makes no sense if only those two methods were all you were referring to.

Answer (score -3):

I'd use .includes() on a string or .indexOf()

`inputType.indexOf('image') === 0`

or

`inputType.includes('image')`

or, if you really want to use regex:

`/^image.*/.test(inputType)`